# Link tumblr photos on theme to permalink page?

Tags: html, tumblr

My tumblr theme currently when you click on picutres just shows a bigger version of the picture itself, however I want the page to link to the permalink page instead.

```
{block:Photo}
<div class="tumblrset">
  <div class="tumblrset-photo-frame" data-height="{PhotoHeight-HighRes}" data-width="{PhotoWidth-HighRes}">
    <a class="tumblrset-photo-wrap" href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" rel="{PostID}">
      <img alt="{PhotoAlt}" class="tumblrset-photo" data-highres="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" src="{PhotoURL-250}"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
{block:Photo}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{PhotoURL-HighRes}` with `{Permalink}`.

```
<a class="tumblrset-photo-wrap" href="{Permalink}" rel="{PostID}">
  <img alt="{PhotoAlt}" class="tumblrset-photo" data-highres="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" src="{PhotoURL-250}"/>
</a>
```

This will work for Photo posts. I am not 100% sure on Photosets, as it depends on the implementation. If it doesn't please update the question with the markup.

Comment: Didn't seem to work for some reason. Might be my theme

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Are you trying to change how **photos** or **photosets** link? There is a difference.